# jekyll won't render on github-pages of project site

Tags: html, dns, jekyll, github-pages

I want to set up 2 different jekyll sites:

https://github.com/Caruso33/caruso33.github.io for my front page to the redirected domain leinss.eu and

https://github.com/Caruso33/traveltobi.de for blog related stuff, to the subdomain blog.leinss.eu (traveltobi.de also points to that).

The user page is rendered all fine, but the project site (traveltobi.de) doesn't work. I set the gh-pages settings to the master/docs branch and put all jekyll related files in this folder github.com/Caruso33/traveltobi.de/docs. However, I only can see the basic HTML page.

Is there a wrong setup in the _config.yml?
CNAME is showed as it should.

I don't know what configuration to change properly.

Comment: After you create a custom domain you won't be able to use project pages.